# Accessing a computed in one of its dependency's subscription

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Consider the following Knockout code:

```
function ViewModel() {
  this.firstName = ko.observable("");
  this.lastName = ko.observable("");
  this.dummyDependency = ko.observable(false);
    this.fullName = ko.computed(function() { return this.dummyDependency() ? this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName() : ""; }, this);

  var self = this;
  this.lastName.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    alert(self.fullName());
  });
};

var myModel = new ViewModel();
myModel.dummyDependency(true);
myModel.firstName("Joe");
myModel.lastName("Smith");
// ---> alerts "Joe "
alert(myModel.fullName());
// ---> alerts "Joe Smith" correctly
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rv8qnjz1/1/) for this code to test.

I understand the reason behind this behaviour, however I have no idea how I could overcome this.  The reason is that **initially** when the computed runs, **it doesn't find the `firstName` and `lastName` as dependency** (because the false flag), so it doesn't subscribe to them.

So when I subscribe to `lastName`, **my subscription will be the first in the subscription list** of `lastName`. Then when I change the flag to `true`, it will force the computed to re-evaluate, and **now it subscribes to both `firstName` and `lastName`**, **BUT** its subscription **will be after mine** in the list. So when I change **lastName**, my subscription fires before the computed's, so I can't get the up to date value.

This example is farly simplified, my real scenario is much more complex, cannot be restructured or redesigned too simply. Does anyone have any idea or trick how this behaviour could be worked around?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? You're subscribing to `lastName` but you're making changes that affects and alerts `fullName`. You should be subscribing to `fullName` if you want to track changes on it.

Comment: @JeffMercado Yes, this is why I noted that this is only a dumb example code. In my real scenario I cannot subscribe to the computed because it may change due to other dependencies as well.

Comment: And that's the point, it's dependencies may change but yours doesn't. You depend on the computed observable, you shouldn't concern yourself with what it depends on. If you had a more concrete example of what you are trying to accomplish here, we could probably steer you in the right direction.

Comment: @JeffMercado Actually you've already steered me in the right direction :) I thought it all over again based on your last comment, and found the point where I've made a bad decision. Thank you, if you can somehow form an answer based on you ideas, I will accept it.

Comment: I'm not sure what was it about what I said that solved your problem. But if were able to figure out the problem, you can definitely answer your own question. Make sure to point out what it was I said that pointed you in the right direction, what kind of change you had to make and possibly an updated version where it works as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I've figured out that I made a bad design decision in my real scenario somewhere deeper. The guidence I got from @JeffMercado in his comments pointed me the right direction about how to deal with complex dependency chains in mind. The key is to make sure that I'm always subscribing to that observable (or computed observable) which I directly use. And if a scneario is not fitting to this paradigm, then that design is bad and have to be refactored.

In my example (which was really just for demonstational proposes) the refactoring is as simple as subscribing to the `fullName` computed instead of the `lastName`, because the action in the subscription directly needs the `fullName`.

Here is the correct version:

```
function ViewModel() {
  this.firstName = ko.observable("");
  this.lastName = ko.observable("");
  this.dummyDependency = ko.observable(false);
    this.fullName = ko.computed(function() { return this.dummyDependency() ? this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName() : ""; }, this);

  var self = this;
  this.fullName.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    alert(self.fullName());
  });
};

var myModel = new ViewModel();
myModel.dummyDependency(true);
myModel.firstName("Joe");
myModel.lastName("Smith");
// ---> alerts "Joe Smith" as expected
```